# How to afk while in-game on Runescape?

Tags: runescape

I want to grow my pet birds whilst doing stuff in real life.
How can I be away from keyboard on Runescape for long periods of time? I have tried putting on rune armour and using air strike on a Lesser Demon in the Wizards tower but the game logs me out anyway after 10 or so minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game will log you out automatically after a period of time of inactivity. There's no in-game way around that.

You *can* use a macro to force activity, however, [that method is against the rules](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Macroing_and_third-party_software), and has a decent chance of being detected. I do not advise, endorse, or recommend this method, and as such, I have not included links to any such macro software.

Other than that, though, there is no way to keep you logged in while AFK. Your best bet is just to be patient and let things happen during regular gameplay.

Comment: I thought about making this an answer only for the laughs but there is a method just kind of ridiculous to set up and technically is not against the rules.  Here is a link to one of many videos showing it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXLUzvn8r-4 I don't know why you would waste time doing it, but it technically is a method of staying 'active' in game without a macro.

Comment: @Fogolicious Hahahahahaha, that's great.

Comment: I really wanted to make it an answer but didn't know if Arqade community would appreciate troll answers very well or not.

Comment: I would have appreciated an answer like that. :D

Comment: @Fogolicious Why would that not be against the rules?  It has to be a coded bot to be illegal?  What if I had a physical robot doing it?

Answer (score 3):

While it is against the game rules to use software methods to prevent automatic logout, hardware methods are specifically allowed. Because moving your mouse on the game screen resets the timer, rigging up a device to jiggle it (or my favorite: hanging an optical mouse in front of a fan) is a legitimate way to stay logged in for longer periods of time.

Comment: It actually quite strange that their rules only apply to "Software".  I know I've played other games where they specifically state that even physical methods of doing that violate the ToS.  I don't know how they would actually _enforce_ such a rule; but it does exist for some games (although for RS it does seem to be strictly software).